# Python - Torch - multilayer perceptron API worse than manually coded?

Tags: python, torchvision

I'm taking a course on Coursera on machine learning and one of the labs was to code the multilayer perceptron manually and compare it to the Torch API. I did so; however, after running both several times the Torch API appears to be ~0.5% worse (~92% vs ~92.5%) than the manual coding leading me to believe I messed up some syntax somewhere.

I don't know for certain, but I assume the problem is in the `MNIST_Perceptron` class... Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

class MNIST_Perceptron(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lin0 = nn.Linear(784, 500)
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(500, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.lin1( F.relu( self.lin0(x) ) )

mnist_train = datasets.MNIST(root="./datasets", train=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor(), download=True)
mnist_test = datasets.MNIST(root="./datasets", train=False, transform=transforms.ToTensor(), download=True)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mnist_train, batch_size=100, shuffle=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mnist_test, batch_size=100, shuffle=False)

## Training
# Instantiate model
model = MNIST_Perceptron()

# Loss and Optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

# Iterate through train set minibatchs 
for images, labels in tqdm(train_loader):
    # Zero out the gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    # Forward pass
    x = images.view(-1, 28*28)
    y = model(x)
    loss = criterion(y, labels)
    # Backward pass
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

## Testing
correct = 0
total = len(mnist_test)

with torch.no_grad():
    # Iterate through test set minibatchs 
    for images, labels in tqdm(test_loader):
        # Forward pass
        x = images.view(-1, 28*28)
        y = model(x)
        
        predictions = torch.argmax(y, dim=1)
        correct += torch.sum((predictions == labels).float())
    
print('Test accuracy: {}'.format(correct/total))
```

Comment: I am taking the same course. Your API solution looks slick.  The code you posted is the higher level nn.Module.  What was your setup in the manual version? I am not sure how is the bias treated between self.lin0 and self.lin1. Is a bias created, is it added? Have you tried asking the question in the PyTorch forum https://discuss.pytorch.org/? Alternatively, have you posted the question in the Coursera class forum?

Comment: sorry, I don't remember